# Why did git not notice this inline change?

Tags: git, merge

I seem to have run into a case where git doesn't notice inline changes when merging..

My master branch had a file with this line:

```
process &block if block
```

And I did a fetch from a git repo, and tried to merge in the changes from the same file, which had a line with:

```
process 1, &block if block
```

But git didn't give a warning about a possible merge conflict, and didn't highlight the line as changed [1]. The change was simply ignored, not updating the file with the line [2].

**Why did git not notice this inline change?** And update the line (since the line was from a later commit)?

**EDIT:**

[1] - git didn't indicate that it had changed when I was doing the conflict resolution (you know, it didn't put in "<<<" in the source code around it). And the succeeding merge commit doesn't show the line as changed in any way (either when running gif diff with colors or looking at the code on github).

[2] - The line came from a repo which held a newer version of the same gem I was working on (so there should be some common commit ancestors with which to do the merge. Also, the line was updated in a later commit on that same repo, so it should be apparent for git that that was in fact an update).

**EDIT:**

In case it plays a role, this was the commit tree before the merge:

**The original gem (common ancestry):**

```
--A
```

**My master branch (actually a fork of the original gem):**

```
--A--  
     \  
      --B
```

(the line wasn't changed in B, but came from A)

**The repo I merged into master (the updated version of the gem):**

```
--A---C---D
```

(the line was updated in D)

Comment: How do you check, whether line has been changed?

Comment: Did you just fetch or fetch & merge (aka pull) the changes from the remote repo?

Comment: You saying "similar" file is suspicious. The file is in the same path, right?

Comment: @CodeBrickie I did a fetch and then a merge.

Comment: What is the exact sequence of commands you executed?

Comment: @Tadeck I checked the file source code on master afterwards (using vim and also inspecting it on github).

Comment: @JanHudec Sorry, it's in the same path, yes. I said "similar" because I thought saying "same" could be interpreted as "identical" (which might be confusing, since we're talking about a difference). I see my assumption backfired, so I changed it back to "same" now. :)

Comment: @CodeBrickie git status says nothing (working directory is clean..).

Comment: @knittl
The exact sequence of commands I executed:
`git fetch savon-upstream/master`
`git merge savon-upstream/master`
>Auto-merging lib/savon/client.rb
>CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in lib/savon/client.rb
`vim client.rb`
(then resolved the highlighted merge conflicts in the same file, added the file, and committed back to master)

Comment: @Magne: If so, then why did you expect it to "_highlight the line as changed_"? Change could be highlighted in some editors, if the change is local and has not been committed. You just merged this change, you should not see it as local, non-commited one.

Comment: @Tadeck With "highlight the line as changed" I meant that git didn't  indicate that it had changed when I was doing the conflict resolution (you know, it didn't put in "<<<" in the source code around it). And the succeeding merge commit doesn't show the line as changed in any way (either when running gif diff with colors or looking at the code on github).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Merge, git or otherwise (sans bugs or incomplete implementations), works by looking up most recent common ancestor of the two branches and than combines *changes* since that point. It is only a conflict if both sides *changed* the line (in different way). If only one side changed it, that change is applied.

In git, you can see changes from merge base to the branch head you want to merge using `git diff HEAD...branch` and changes from merge base to your local head using `git diff branch...HEAD` (generally, `git diff`*left*`...`*right* shows changes from common ancestor of *left* and *right* to *right*). The commands are for before you do the merge. After the fact, it would be `git diff HEAD^..HEAD^2` and `git diff HEAD^2..HEAD^` (`HEAD^` is first parent, `HEAD^2` is right parent).

You can also see all revisions since the merge base by replacing `git diff` with `gitk` in above commands or just ask for what the mere base is using `git merge-base HEAD branch`.

Comment: Could it be that the problem somehow occured since I was trying to merge a stale fork of a gem with the newer version of the original gem? They share some common ancestors, but it seems as if the merge as a whole went rather well (except for the noted problem). In any case, the newer version of the gem had changed the line in a later commit from when the fork was made, but git didn't apply that change for some reason.

Comment: @Magne: Git did apply all changes that were made since the common ancestor. For some reason the selected base does not match your expectation of it. Open the history in gitk and check what the common base is. Also note, that there may be more than one most recent common ancestor, in which case git will merge them first and use the result of that as merge base ("recursive" merge strategy).

Comment: You are right. Gitk shows that the common base is way earlier than I thought. And the history from that point up until the expected base was in fact duplicated on top after the expected base. Could it be because the author of the repo had retroactively deleted some of the commits in that part of history. Could that have played a part? What can change the SHA1 IDs (i assume those are what git uses to find a common base)?

Comment: The SHA1 ID of the parent is part of the hashed content of the commit, so if a commit is rewritten, all it's descendants also have to be. I wouldn't say this is caused by rewriting. Probably the author couldn't make up his mind, so he made the changes, than either reverted them or made a branch before them and than done them again. And while the behaviour of merge in presence of reverts is logical, it's somewhat counter-intuitive, so that might be the issue.

Comment: I've compared with the separate commit history of the repo I used, and it wasn't due to the author changing his mind. (The duplicated commits match exactly, timestamp and all, except for the parent and tag info). It seems to me that with git, it's really dangerous to merge with a repo you don't control.. If the repo's author has modified it's history, then the merge will screw up (not finding the same common ancestors). I guess the moral is: Don't fork a fork of a gem and then merge it with the original gem. Thank you for your time and help, Jan! :-)

Comment: @Magne: Yes, it might be. If the author rewrote history (usually done by using `rebase`), than there are several parallel histories that are hard to merge. While `rebase` is extremely useful while cooking your changes locally, one must never ever use it on published repository, otherwise it will cause problems like you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

During the merge index holds 3 versions of each file.

```
$ git show :1:file.txt  # the file in a common ancestor of both branches  
$ git show :2:file.txt  # the version from HEAD.  
$ git show :3:file.txt  # the version from MERGE_HEAD.
```

More details on merge [here](http://book.git-scm.com/5_advanced_branching_and_merging.html)